# Is there a way to convert this powershell script to C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to convert this code to C#.

```
Function CheckFileInstalled {

param (
    [string]$pathProg     = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe",
    [string]$nameProg     = "Winrar"
)

$testFileProg = Test-Path $pathProg

$x86 = ((Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") |
    Where-Object { $_.GetValue( "DisplayName" ) -like "*$nameProg*" } ).Length -gt 0;

$x64 = ((Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") |
    Where-Object { $_.GetValue( "DisplayName" ) -like "*$nameProg*" } ).Length -gt 0;


return ( $testFileProg -and ($x86 -or $x64) )

}

if( CheckFileInstalled ) {
    Write-Host "Program installed." 
}
else {
    Write-Host "Failed to install."
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to re-write this script in C#. But could you clarify what do you want exactly? Like a command line application with the same parameters? You will certainly loose parameter auto-complete feature anyway. Also, have you done any attempts to do that?

Comment: Hi Max! I want the exact same thing mostly. I want to check the path for the application and also check the registry for it. So 1 variable for the path and 1 for the registry check. If both returns true, it will say "Application has been installed correctly."

Answer (score 2):

Try this, but you might need administrator rights for registry

```
public bool CheckFileInstalled(string pathProg, string nameProg)
{
    bool pathExist = Directory.Exists(pathProg);
    bool x86 = false;
    bool x64 = false;

    RegistryKey x86Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", true);
    if(x86Key.GetValueNames().Contains(nameProg)) x86 = true;

    RegistryKey x64Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", true);
    if(x64Key.GetValueNames().Contains(nameProg)) x64 = true;

    return (pathExist && (x86 || x64));
}
```

Comment: Hi. It looks like it's working but you are right, it's asking me for access in registry. Is there a way to do that?